# Transforming target data (angles/degrees) such that 1 degree and 359 degrees are treated similarly

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm working on a model that predicts angles. What's a good way to transform the targets (currently they take on values 0 to 360 degrees) such that close angles are treated similarly? I suspect leaving them as they are now isn't optimal as values close to 360 and 0 are similar, yet have totally different magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use sine and cosine transformation for them! Of course, your model will not predict them perfectly, so you need to re-normalize your results after prediction. See the sample code:

```
# predicting the angle (in radians)
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
# generate toy data
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.normal(size=(100, 2))
y = np.arctan2(np.dot(X, [1,2]), np.dot(X, [3,0.4]))
# simple prediction
model = MLPRegressor(random_state=42, activation='tanh', max_iter=10000)
y_simple_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, y)
# transformed prediction
joint = cross_val_predict(model, X, np.column_stack([np.sin(y), np.cos(y)]))
y_trig_pred = np.arctan2(joint[:,0], joint[:,1])
# compare
print(r2_score(y, y_simple_pred)) # R^2 about 0.53
print(r2_score(y, y_trig_pred))   # R^2 about 0.85
```